# Why is there no possibility of no solution in homogeneous systems

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for a newbie question, but can u please tell me, why there's no chance for such thing?

For example:

5 | 0

is a homogeneous system, because of the 0 at the end. and 
    5 =/= 0, so... 
doesn't this mean there's no solution?

What am I missing here, plz help.

Comment: is that because:   if 5 | 0, then it means 5x=0, and that means that x must be 0, and it's basically the same as 0 | 0. Correct?

Comment: The System 5|0 is a "shorter form"  of the equation 5x=0 (assuming you mean a System of linear equations) each homogenous System of linear equations has the solution of all variables being equal to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example means $5x=0$, which gives you $x=0$. Remember the left side is the coefficient matrix. The numbers are coefficients of linear equations.

For a homogeneous system, zero is always a solution. So there is always this solution, which is the so called trivial solution.

Comment: Lol. Just a second before your answer thought about it! Thanks for helping!